# Delivery fee calculator is not displaying information

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on a project that involves a google map calculating a delivery fee. I have it coded out that it shows up in a WordPress page, but the submit button will not work.

The correct function of this is suppose to be as follows:

1. From address is pre-filled in
2. To address is entered by customer
3. submit button is clicked, and a delivery fee is shown with the parameters expressed in the code, along with driving directions.

But as of now, the page just reloads and no delivery fee or directions are displayed.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
      // <![CDATA[
      window.onload = function() {
        initialize(61.5705194, -149.118133);
      }
      // ]]>
    </script>
    <input id="day_more_five" type="hidden" value="2" />
    <input id="day_less_five" type="hidden" value="0" />
    <input id="night_more_five" type="hidden" value="10" />
    <input id="night_less_five" type="hidden" value="10" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
      // <![CDATA[
      function get_distance(form) {
        from = form.place_from.value;
        to = form.place_to.value;
        calcRoute(from, to);
      }
      // ]]>
    </script>
    <div id="abgdc-wrap">
      <div id="map_canvas" style="position: relative; width: 100%px;  
                                  height: 600px; margin: 0px auto; border: solid 5px #003;"></div>
      <form action="" method="post" name="form1">
        <table class="abgdc-table">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>From:
                <input class="txt" disabled="disabled" name="place_from" type="text" value="FROM ADDRESS GOES HERE" />
              </td>
              /tr>
            <tr>
              <td>     To:
                <input class="txt" name="place_to" type="text" />
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="display: none;">
              <td>Travel Time:
                <input id="day_time" style="display: none;" checked="checked" name="travel_time" type="radio" value="day" /> Day
                <input id="night_time" style="display: none;" name="travel_time" type="radio" value="night" /> Night</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <input style="width: 100%!important;" 
                       type="button" 
                       value="Get Quote" 
                       onclick="get_distance(this.form)" />
                <input id="map_zoom" type="hidden" value="7" />
                <input id="curr_format" type="hidden" value="$" />
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </form>
      <div id="distance"></div>
      <div id="steps"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: `will not work` is not really descriptive. Is the route not calculated? Du you want to submit the form after the route is calculated? Is there any error message in the console? You should always describe the expected behaviour and how this differs from your actual code.

Comment: My apologies. The route is not calculated, and a delivery fee is not displayed. When the address is entered in the "to" text box and the submit button is clicked, it should display a delivery fee, and directions. Does not need to be submitted, just displayed. Does that help? As of now, the page just reloads and no delivery fee or directions are displayed.

Comment: Because nothing is displayed the problem/error is most likely within your `calcRoute`. The code you provide here does not include anything that would display something.